# Can't access spPageContextInfo nor spClientSidePageContext

Tags: sharepoint-online

Normally I was accessing user details on client end using either spPageContextInfo or spClientSidePageContext (or using _spPageContextInfo or _spClientSidePageContext version). For some reason though, these two values return undefined on my Client's website.

Do you have any idea why this occurs and how I can alternatively fetch name and second name in browser console?

It's SharePoint Online.

Comment: are you accessing _spPageContextInfo in SharePoint Add In(webpart) ?

Comment: no, I need to access it using external script. As long as it's present in DOM I should be able to fetch these details but in Chrome Console id returns undefined

Comment: what is page type on which you are running in chrome console? does it have default master page? i

Comment: before using _spPageContextInfo, check if 'core.js' file is loaded on page or not.